# How do I convince this button to do something when it is clicked?

Tags: plugins, php, ajax, javascript, forms

I'm trying to use ajax to give me an alert when I click a button. Eventually I want it to do some form validation, but for now I would be happy just to see the alert.

I've read the docs and about a dozen similar questions, but for some reason I still can't get my version to work.

I'm hoping someone else can see whatever it is that I'm missing.

This is what I have:

```
// In the php files

add_action( 'wp_ajax_ecbs_validate_data', 'ecbs_validate_data' );

add_action( 'in_admin_header', 'my_ajax_button' );

function my_ajax_button()
{
    // This gets echoed to a form in another function
    return '<button id="ecbs-submit" type="button" value="Submit" class="button-primary">Submit</button>';
}

// In the .js file

// Do something when button is clicked?
$j("#ecbs-submit").on('click', function() {
    try {
        alert('something is happening');
        $j.post(ajaxurl, {
            action: 'ecbs_validate_data',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                //data returned from php
                alert('success');
            }
        });
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(err);
    }
});
```

I assume that since the alert is not happening, the script is not getting called at all.

The JavaScript above is not the only thing in the file, though. This is the full script: Maybe a conflict?

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function() {

    // Updates the $ecbs-eit-area div when a template is 
    // selected from a drop box.
    $j("#ecbs_styles").change(function() {
        var str = "";
        $j("#ecbs_styles option:selected").each(function() {
            str = $j("#ecbs_styles").val();
            //if (str !== 'dummy')
            //{
            try {
                $j.post(ajaxurl, {
                    data: {template: str},
                    action: 'ecbs_populate_admin_template'
                }, function(response) {
                    $j("#ecbs-edit-area").html(response);
                }
                );
            }
            catch (err) {
                alert(err);
            }
        });
    })
            .change();

    // Do something when button is clicked?
    $j("#ecbs-submit").on('click', function() {
        try {
            alert('something is happening');
            $j.post(ajaxurl, {
            action: 'ecbs_validate_data',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                //data returned from php
                alert('success');
            }
        });
        }
        catch (err) {
            alert(err);
        }
    });
});
```

And, if you're curious, the only thing in `ecbs_validate_data()` is:

```
function ecbs_validate_data()
{
    die ('something happened');
}
```

---

The plot thickens! I created another button and changed my javascript to use that button and it works. I'll have to play with it some more to see if I can figure out what the deal is.

---

Ah ha! When the button is inside my edit-area div it doesn't work, but when I put it anywhere outside of there it does. I'm finally getting somewhere with this.

Comment: Did you check if the script is loading or not? You can do this on Chrome by doing: right-click + inspect element + Network tab. Network tab should show your script if it is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if anyone has the same problem, I think this was the issue:

I had the button inside of a div that was hidden until the user selected an option from the drop box. I think the problem was that the ajax script wasn't connecting with the button, because the button didn't exist when the page and script originally loaded. If that makes sense. I changed it so that the button is in a different part of the page and hides after the page loads and it works perfectly now.